# firebase 3 : avoid displayName duplicates

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase 3.

When adding or changing displayName, is it possible to check if this displayName is already used (to avoid duplicates) ?

Comment: you can use `.exists()` however you should probably check you've designed your JSON structure correctly, as a duplicate wouldn't occur in firebase, it would merely overwrite what is already there

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to avoid duplicates in properties such as `displayName`. I entered it as a feature request for you on: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Is this already inside Firebase v3.x or under consideration for future milestone?